# Error using babel-loader with npm package.json module field

Tags: reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6, babel-loader, flow-typed

I have a library that I'm building as a React component library that gets built with webpack. I have a second project ( call it `todo app` ) that is attempting to pull components from the first. I'm using the npm package.json `module` field to specify the `src` directory from the component library so that my second project can pull the components directly.

The error I'm seeing is that the flow type definitions from the component library are not being parsed correctly even though the todo app also uses flow type definitions. Here is an example of the error I'm seeing:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@<npm_org>/<npm_package>/src/components/Header/index.jsx
12:5 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:5) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import styles from'./styles'
> type Props = {
|   classes: Object,
|   handleDrawerToggle: () => void,
@ ./node_modules/@<npm_org>/<npm_package>/src/index.js 1:0-55 1:0-55
@ ./src/modules/dashboard/components/presenter.jsx
@ ./src/modules/dashboard/components/container.jsx
@ ./src/modules/dashboard/components/index.js
@ ./src/modules/router/index.jsx
@ ./src/modules/root/App/index.jsx
@ ./src/main.jsx
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 @babel/polyfill ./src/main.jsx
```

both babel configs are using the react preset and build correctly independently. If I use `yarn link` locally the build is successful - it's only when I go through the publishing process that it breaks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Happy to post my webpack / babel configs if helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Flow preset? That syntax isn't react-related.

Comment: Yep, I do have the flow preset on both projects